# Python Google Maps API free

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-maps

I want to ask that is there any way to use google map APIs free with python to extract (addesses, distance, traffic) information.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no free lunch. Google's services are payed (for normal usage), but there are (open-source) alternatives.

You could setup your own routing/distance server with services like http://project-osrm.org/ and http://opentransportmap.info/, and lists like https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection.

With OSRM, it will cost you time and computer resources, so not free, but no services fees or licenses. That is, if you have the time and a decent computer, you can install the OSRM software for free, and replicate parts of the google maps API with similar results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a $200/monthly credit for Google Maps API usage.

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-credits#monthly

You will still be required to setup billing information.